# Посчитать сколько элементов в массиве всего при помощи цикла foreach, не используя функцию count

Tags: php, циклы

дан массив, нужно подсчитать количество элементов не используя функцию `count`

```
$numbers = ['0', '6', '12', '18', '24', '30', '36', '42', '48', '54', '60', '66', '72', '78', '84', '90'];
```

Comment: В чём у вас затруднение?

Comment: В вашем массиве 16 элементов

Answer (score 3):

```
$numbers = ['0', '6', '12', '18', '24', '30', '36', '42', '48', '54', '60', '66', '72', '78', '84', '90'];

foreach([1, 2, 3] as $_); // считаем до трёх
end($numbers);
echo (key($numbers)??-1) + 1;
```

Comment: Но ведь тут нет foreach :)

Comment: ой, надо исправлять

Comment: Чёрт, а хитро))

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = ['0', '6', '12', '18', '24', '30', '36', '42', '48', '54', '60', '66', '72', '78', '84', '90'];
$string = '';

foreach ($numbers as $number) { 
    $string .= substr((string)$number, 0, 1);
}

echo 'Всего чисел: ' . (strlen($string));
```

Comment: Первый ответ был лучше!

Comment: @vp_arth * размышляет добавить ли его *

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = ['0', '6', '12', '18', '24', '30', '36', '42', '48', '54', '60', '66', '72', '78', '84', '90'];

foreach ($numbers as $i => $number) { }

echo 'Всего чисел: ' . ($i + 1);
```